# Finite geometric sequence with a ratio greater than 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the recurrence relation:

$ t(n)= 3T(n/2)+Cn$ (if $n>2$)

$t(2)=C$            (otherwise)

I know that there is the Master Theorem but I am trying to use the tree method. This is what I have so far: the total work that was done in each level is: $Cn(q/2)^j$ 
there are $\log n$ levels and therefore the sum of the work can be represented with the following geometric series:

$Cn\sum_{j=0}^L(3/2)^j$

$L=\log_2 n-1$

It's obvious that the ratio is greater than 1. Is there a way to solve this? I can't find an answer anywhere

Comment: What is $j$? What is "work"?

Comment: I had a little trouble with the MathJax. J is the index of the summation. Nevermind the work. I am trying to understand how to solve the series above

Comment: I'm a little surprised that you can't find an answer for this; just searching 'finite geometric series' finds me a bunch of hits.  The short short version is that $\sum_{i=0}^nr^i = \frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$.

Comment: I sure tried to look for such a formula before writing this question. Could you send the link please?